# How to delete all metadata from all JPEG files in folder using ImageMagick?

Tags: metadata, jpeg, imagemagick

I have many JPEG files in folder D:\folder. I want to delete all metadata from all JPEG files in this folder. I used ImageMagick. I made:

`magick mogrify -strip "D:\folder\*"`

Am I right?

Comment: Did you try it yet? What were your results?

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, Tetsujin. Yes, I made this command. How to check that there is no any metadata in all JPEG files became?

Comment: I believe this would be a destructive recompression of the jpeg.  To remove metadata you're better off using something like exiftool or exiv2.

Comment: @StarGeek Thank you, StarGeek. How to check jpeg received destructive recompression or not?

Comment: Use [ImageMagick Compare option](https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) to see the compare the before and after images.